# How to Subset Tall Data for Graphing

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, visualization

My data is in a tall format. I'm interested in producing line graphs using ggplot for each region. However, I keep receiving errors that the aesthetics must either be length 1 or the same as the data.

### Hard-coded solution:

```
date_q <- HPF$date[1:167]
CumulativeSubset_region1 <- HPF$BaseCumulative[1:167]
ggplot(HPF[1:167, ], aes(x = date_q, y= CumulativeSubset_region1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

### Without hard-coding:

```
ggplot(data = HPF, aes(x=date, y= BaseC)) + geom_line(na.rm = FALSE) + theme_light()
```

As you can see, the spikes are due to the fact that the date range is constant throughout all regions, but regional cumulatives are different.

### Data:

```
#Rows 1-3 (Region 1 Sample): 
dput(head(HPF[1:3, ]))
    structure(list(region = c(1, 1, 1), path = c(1, 1, 1), date = c(20140215, 
    20140515, 20140815), index_value = c(1, 1.033852765, 1.041697122
    ), index = 0:2, counter = 1:3, BaseQoQ = c(NA, 0.033852765, 0.00758749917354029
    ), BaseCumulative = c(100, 103.3852765, 104.1697122), StressCumulative = c(110, 
    113.3852765, 114.1697122), StressQoQ = c(NA, 0.0307752409090909, 
    0.00691832065162346)), .Names = c("region", "path", "date", "index_value", 
    "index", "counter", "BaseQoQ", "BaseCumulative", "StressCumulative", 
    "StressQoQ"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))

#Rows 168:200 (Region 2 Sample):
dput(head(HPF[168:200, ]))
    structure(list(region = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), path = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), date = c(20140215, 20140515, 20140815, 20141115, 20150215, 
    20150515), index_value = c(1, 1.014162265, 1.01964828, 1.009372314, 
    1.007210703, 1.018695493), index = 0:5, counter = 1:6, BaseQoQ = c(NA, 
    0.014162265, 0.00540940556489744, -0.0100779515854232, -0.0021415398163972, 
    0.0114025694582001), BaseCumulative = c(100, 101.4162265, 101.964828, 
    100.9372314, 100.7210703, 101.8695493), StressCumulative = c(110, 
    111.4162265, 111.964828, 110.9372314, 110.7210703, 101.8695493
    ), StressQoQ = c(NA, 0.0128747863636363, 0.00492389230216839, 
    -0.00917785181610786, -0.00194849914020834, -0.0799443229370588
    )), .Names = c("region", "path", "date", "index_value", "index", 
    "counter", "BaseQoQ", "BaseCumulative", "StressCumulative", "StressQoQ"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `ggplot` to do the lines separately for each region. This will be implied if you use aesthetics like `linetype` or `color` (and you'll automatically get a nice legend telling you which line is which).

If you want the aesthetics of the region lines to be identical, you can use the `group` aesthetic to let ggplot know which points should be connected.

Using your little bit of sample data:

```
ggplot(HPF, aes(x = date, y = BaseCumulative, group = factor(region))) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

As `region` is a categorical variable, I'd recommend making it a `factor` - this will work well if you use an aesthetic like `color` or `linetype`.

I'd also recommend that you look into using an actual `Date` class - it will make your axis accurate so you don't have giant gaps between December and January.

```
HPF$date = as.Date(as.character(HPF$date), format = "%Y%M%d")
HPF$region = factor(HPF$region)
ggplot(HPF, aes(x = date, y= BaseCumulative, linetype = factor(region))) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.. Now let's say I'm interested in subsetting and plotting one region at a time. How would that be achieved? I plan on putting this all into a shiny dashboard and using a dropdown to select and dynamically generate the correct plot.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Pull out whatever subset you want and plot it. See `?subset` or pretty much any introduction to R for how to subset data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the `colour` aesthetic to your region variable, if the region is made into a categorical variable with `factor`. This is me interpreting your desired output as a single line for each region. I also would recommend fixing your date formatting to make a prettier plot, but that's not the question. Using `region` and `region2` as objects from your `dput`:

```
library(tidyverse)
HPF <- bind_rows(region, region2) %>%
  mutate(region = factor(region))

ggplot(data = HPF) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y= BaseCumulative, colour = region), na.rm = FALSE) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

You can get the same effect by assigning region to other aesthetics too, like `linetype`, and you can control the colours generated with different colour scales.

Comment: Thank you for this.. Now let's say I'm interested in subsetting and plotting one region at a time. How would that be achieved? I plan on putting this all into a shiny dashboard and using a dropdown to select and dynamically generate the correct plot.

Comment: @datanalyst: Speaking only for myself: I find it quite annoying when an answer is provided and then there a follow-on question that is different but no upvote or checkmark is offered to the respondent.